# How to get translateX transition to work in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover

This code works in Chrome but not Firefox. Any ideas on how I can fix it? The door is supposed to open when you hover over it and the landscape image will scroll across but in Firefox the door won't fully open unless the mouse is on the right edge. (I'm not allowed to change the html or use anything other than css)

https://jsfiddle.net/rr3nj7dr/

```
<ul id="calendar"><li><div class = "door">15</div></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're `translate()`-ing `.door` (which will move `.door`), trigger the transition when you hover the parent `li`, not when you hover `.door`.

```css
  #calendar {
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #calendar li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/C68wDiS.jpg);
  }
  
  .door {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left 0px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 110px;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: grey;
  }
  
  #calendar li:hover .door {
    transform: translateX(110px);
  }
  
  #calendar li:hover {
    animation: slidingfour 3s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  @keyframes slidingfour {
    0% {
      background-position: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: -330px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<ul id="calendar">
  <li>
    <div class="door">15</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@-moz-keyframes
-moz-animation
i hope that the picture helps you :)
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAVmo.png

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Try this.

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(110px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-transform: translateX(110px); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform: translateX(110px); /* IE 9 */
```